How to propagate a PropertyAttribute on a class to its methods in the XML output?
I have annotated a test class with an NUnit.Framework.PropertyAttribute. This results in the XML test results file having this attribute as property child element of the element that represents this test class.
Now I also want this attribute as property child element of the elements that represent the test methods, but I do not want to annotate the test methods with this attribute explicitly. What are the best ways to do this?
It may be possible by writing an XSLT stylesheet and passing its location to the command line runner. But since I have no experience with XSLT, I may prefer another approach.

Also posted at https://github.com/nunit/nunit/discussions/4713.
